# Differentiating $\int_{\cos x}^{4x}\cos u^5 du$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives

> Use part one of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find the derivative of $$\int_{\cos x}^{4x}\cos u^5 du$$

My answer: $$y\;'=\sin x (\cos^5(\cos x))+4\cos^5(4x)$$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definite integral is $$F(4x)-F(\cos(x)),$$ where $F$ is the antiderivative. Now differentiation yields:
$$4F'(4x)+\sin(x)F'(\cos(x)),$$ where $F'(x)=\cos(x^5).$

The final answer will be:
$$4\cos((4x)^5)+\sin(x)\cos(\cos^5(x)).$$

Answer (score 1):

Well, $$\cos^5u\neq\cos u^5$$
$${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest, approach the problem in the most general form, that is to say $$A=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} F(u) \, du$$ Applying the first part  of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus gives $$A=F\big(b(x)\big) b'(x)-F\big(a(x)\big) a'(x)$$ Now, for your case, $$F(u)=\cos(u^5)$$ $$a(x)=\cos(x)$$ $$b(x)=4x$$ $$a'(x)=-\sin(x)$$ $$b'(x)=4$$ I am sure that you can take from here and finish.